# How do I search for all my git repositories on my Mac?

Tags: git, macos

I'm curious where I've scattered my git repositories across my mac. I'm trying to figure out how I could do a search to find them all so I can organize my life a bit. How can I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Find is your friend. a .git folder will exist in each of your repositories so finding the location of them will give you all your repos.

```
find /Users/username -name ".git" -print
```

Comment: too slow..., maybe there is another way?

Comment: If you want to skip the `Library` and `.Trash` directories: `find ~ -path ~/.Trash -prune -o -path ~/Library -prune -o -type d -name .git -print`

Answer (score 9):

Use `find`:

```
find ~ -name .git
```

This searches for the `.git` directory that is created in all (non-bare) Git repositories.

Choice of a suitable file to search for to find bare repositories is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Actually it searches for anything named .git, for directories you want -type d, as well

Comment: @ergosys Good point, but how many regular files named ".git" do you have lying around? If the answer is > 0, what's in these files?

Comment: @Laurence Nuclear launch codes, porn, encryption keys, grocery lists, etc.

Comment: This did it in the least characters. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Laurence, true enough, but false statements demand correction by the pedantry.

Comment: @ergosys It was more "incomplete" than false. It does search for "for the .git directory that is created in all (non-bare) Git repositories". It also searches for files named .git. It also searches for directories named .git that weren't created by git.

Answer (score 7):

In shell:

```
find $HOME -type d -name ".git"
```

Comment: I forgot- Mac OSX ships with BSD 'findutils', while 'xtype' is GNU-specific, I believe. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have `locate`, this should be much faster:

```
locate .git |grep git$
```

If you have gnu locate or mlocate, this will select only the git dirs:

```
locate -ber \\.git$
```

Comment: $ locate -ber \\.git$
locate: illegal option -- b
usage: locate [-0Scims] [-l limit] [-d database] pattern ...

default database: `/var/db/locate.database' or $LOCATE_PATH

Comment: Ha, this is like ssh except over SO :)

Comment: "WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist." - should I create database?