# Listing Local and Remote Git Repos using Git shell

Tags: git, github, git-svn

Is there any way to list all the remote as well as local repositories of one using git shell on Windows? I normally use GitHub (the GUI version) where local and remote repositories are listed in GUI.

What I have tried is:

`$ git remote -a`
`$ git remote -r`

I have also tried to play with history command, and browsed through some tutorials, but none of them mentions a clear cut solution. Please see if you can respond.

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off just trying to search your harddrive for .git directories. Then, look within each of those for remotes.

Comment: Are you looking for `git remote -v` ?

Comment: Janos, I actually did try that but to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I search for all my git repositories on my Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319290/how-do-i-search-for-all-my-git-repositories-on-my-mac)

Answer (score 2):

There is no central place where a list of all your repos are stored. A git repository is nothing but a folder with some fancy content. But that means that you can find all git repos by looking for exactly that.

Do a search on all your drives for `.git`. If you have bare repos there, it might get a little bit more difficult. You could try looking for files that are called `HEAD`, though that might give you some false positives. Maybe files named `config` that contain the string `repositoryformatversion`.

Answer (score 0):

if You are using POSIX style OS, you can run this command.

```
find / -name ".git"
```

Basically Git does not have a centeral repository that contains all the repositories. This command just search all the folders for a `.git` file.

Likewise on Windows or Mac, one can search for `.git` as well and it will list all the git repositories.