# How to find local repo?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a few git repos. I can *easily* find remote repo in my [gitlab list of personal projects](https://gitlab.com/users/adammajewski/projects?nav_source=navbar), but sometimes I can't find my local repo.

I know that I can [list all local git repositories using find](http://www.sixarm.com/about/git-how-to-find-git-repository-directories.html) :

```
find ~ -type d -name .git
```

or add info about local repository to README.md file, like [here, see bottom](https://gitlab.com/adammajewski/repeated-square-root-).

There are also [other local methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319290/how-do-i-search-for-all-my-git-repositories-on-my-mac)

**Is it possible to find such information in the remote repo ?**

**What information about local repo are in the remote repo ?**

--- edit -----------------------

**Is it safe to put information about local repo online ?**

**Where I can find references that git is agnostic distributed system?**

Comment: Do you forget where you checked them out? You are leaving out some info. This doesn't make sense. Are you trying to access other people's local repos?

Comment: Seems like you're basically asking us how to search your file system. Git can't find repos from outside a repo.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon I try to acces my own local repo, but I forget it's directory.

Comment: Why not check them all out to the same directory? My Documents/repos in Windows or ~/repos in Linux.

Comment: @isherwood I ask if there are any informations in the remote repo about my local repo

Comment: Nope. Git is an agnostic distributed system. There's no connection there.

Comment: You clone always clone the repo again.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon OK, but I can lost some data which was not transfered to remote repo

Comment: It's like asking your car where you left your keys. Sorry but you're on your own.

Comment: Got it. If you have indexing turned on. You can try `locate .git`. That will search system wide but it's quick.

Comment: @ isherwood I think that car manufacturer ( in case of all new cars) knows exact position of car (:-))

Comment: @ EncryptedWatermelon Find gives me 90 directories, locate gives 14600 directories ( with /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-46/scripts/.gitignore which is not my repo) so I think that find is better for such task

Comment: @ isherwood  I thin that your comment answers one of my questions, so you can change it to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I search for all my git repositories on my Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319290/how-do-i-search-for-all-my-git-repositories-on-my-mac)

Comment: On Unix the tools are the same: `find` and `locate`. `locate` is much faster but requires nightly run of `updatedb` and doesn't show files/directories (repositories in your case) created today (`updatedb` doesn't update the DB yet).